# WordPress, finding css for Roots theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I hired a guy to make a WordPress website for me, http://www.brilliantzenaudio.com, and I need to make some changes. I'm a programmer (C++ and Python) so I'm going to attempt these changes myself. Apparently the guy I hired based the WordPress site on the Roots theme. I've been digging through some of the php code and I notice many "div" elements that have id's and class's like "header" and such. I assumed that the styling for these elements came from a css file somewhere. The only one I can find is style.css. And it has nothing but comments! Where can I find the code that styles these div elements?

```
/*
Theme Name:         Roots
Theme URI:          http://www.rootstheme.com/
Description:        Roots is a starting WordPress theme made for developers that's based on HTML5 Boilerplate and Bootstrap. <a href="https://github.com/retlehs/roots/contributors">Contribute on GitHub</a>
Version:            6.4.0
Author:             Ben Word
Author URI:         http://benword.com/

License:            MIT License
License URI:        http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
*/
```

Comment: The roots theme is an excellent choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find your css in `/assets/css/app.css`. Roots does not use `style.css`.

The roots theme places all your css/images etc into a folder called `assets`.

Inside assets you will find a folder called `css`.

Inside there you will find a file called `app.css` - this is what he should be using if he's using the roots theme.

**Note:** the `assets` folder can either be in your `root` folder or in your `theme` folder, depending on how the roots theme was configured.